Emergent Behavior: Observer-Constructed or Observer-Independent behavior of systems
I am seeking works that align with the following thesis: The emergent behaviors claimed to be observed in certain phenomena are not inherent to the phenomena themselves but are artifacts of the mental representations and interpretations of researchers, who may be unaware of this process. This perspective challenges the notion that emergent properties naturally arise from interactions within a system, proposing instead that these behaviors are constructions dependent on and internal to the observer.
Are there theoretical perspectives that support this observer-centric interpretation of emergent phenomena? If so, which authors should I research to learn more?
*Just to be clear, I am not questioning the existence of anthills doing anthill things, societies doing societal things, or brains doing brain things. I am questioning the idea that emergent behavior is something real, intrinsic, and objective to the phenomenon being studied.

An example of what I am asking for can be found here: [https://www.lesswrong.com/posts/8QzZKw9WHRxjR4948/the-futility-of-emergence]. However, I would appreciate more examples.

That's not what that less wrong article says

How is emergent behavior different from other causes in this picture?

@TKoL I realized my initial interpretation was incorrect. However, my question may still relate to the blog's content, as it criticizes the term "emergent" as an empty explanation. The article argues that labeling something as "emergent" often provides no additional understanding and serves as a superficial substitute for more detailed explanations, similar to the old use of "magical" for poorly understood phenomena. If the emergent phenomenon is not real and is merely a byproduct generated by the perception, then it is reasonable to assume that it is not useful.

@DavidGudeman In this line of thought, emergent behavior would not be a real entity existing independently of the observer. Instead, it would be an illusion present in our perception. Some people might believe it is an intrinsic behavior of the object, but in reality, it is a perceptual construction.

But what reason do you have for thinking emergent behavior is different?

I'll use an analogy with a map. Different maps of an environment can have various resolutions and aspects. In Google Maps, there is a point where distinctions between cities and small streets disappear. The more you zoom in, the fewer human details you see, revealing more natural topography. Similarly, humans adjust the level of detail in our representations of other phenomena based on perspective and need.

I believe many people suffer from naive realism, thinking that the features of their maps represent intrinsic structures of the phenomenon itself, rather than artifacts produced by their perceptions.

@DavidGudeman The distinction between emergent behavior and cause is that one is not real, and the other may or may not be real depending on the interpretation of the meaning of the word 'cause'.

I'm looking for a principled difference here, not just your declaration that a difference exists. Why would you think that a cause that takes place directly by contact is more real than a cause that occurs as a result of a complex relationship? What reason do you have to think that contact-like causes aren't just just a construction of the observer's perception but emergent causes are? You are just saying it's so without giving any reason.

@DavidGudeman I apologize, but I don't believe this feed of comments is the most suitable for constructing a complex argument. A different channel might be more appropriate for that purpose. My primary interest in this question is identifying which authors have questioned the ontological reality ascribed to the concept of "emergent behavior."

I edited the question hoping to improve it.

@RaphaelAugusto, I wasn't asking you to answer the question in the comments. I was pointing out what I see as a weakness in your question, which ought to be addressed by fixing the question.

Emergentism is opposed to the view of the good old reductionism which your cited ref takes, thus it's not really about observer-constructed or observer-independent behavior of systems (for example, seeing a same greenish quale induced by a common external green thing by many healthy people is both individual observer-independent and observer-constructed at least under the most popular representationalism instead of direct realism in philosophy of mind). So your titular thesis about the antimony between observer-independent and observer-constructed doesn't actually exist...

Do tornadoes actually exist, or are we just imagining them? If there were no humans, would there still be tornadoes?

You ask:

Are there theoretical perspectives that support this observer-centric interpretation of emergent phenomena? If so, which authors should I research to learn more?

Undoubtedly yes. In literature, there are different approaches to dealing with the creation of an ontology. One can say that there are atoms and atomic behavior and somehow cells and cellular behaviors emerge from them. Or one can say that atoms and cells are simply a linguistic way of labeling in a compositional fashion physical reality and speculate in some sense that atoms and cells are mereological creatures we invent to describe the stuff out there. As Berto and Plebani put it:

In some strongly monistic ontologies of material objects, which have been grouped under the label of stuff theory... objects are taken as mere spatiotemporal occupiers... What actually is out there in the material world is just stuff... Our carving activities select some spatiotemporal portions of the world as salient, but this depends on our cognitive apparatus, more than on the world itself... The monist ontologist may [even] refuse to distinguish... between material objects and the regions of space they [are said to] occupy. (p.103, Ontology and Meta-ontology).

They provide references for stuff theory:

Sidelle, A. (1998), Necessity, Essence, and Individuation. Ithaca, NY: Cornell U.P.
Heller, M. (1990), The Ontology of Physical Objects. Cambridge: Cambridge U.P.
Jubien, M. (1993), Ontology, Modality and the Fallacy of Reference Cambridge: Cambridge U.P.

This view has some appeal in resolving the contention between scientific realism and instrumentalism in the favor of instrumentalists. On the view of stuff theory, the scientific notion of emergence is a function of embodied cognition (SEP) and the representational theory of mind. That is to say, that as the external world affects our body through transduction, emergence is a result of how our bodies including brains construct a representation of the external world and is not a real property of real things in the external world. And if conceptualism is to be believed and our perception affected by our conceptual representations, then even our conscious representations (SEP) are not objective reports of real things, but rather much inline with Kant's notion of Ding an sich, are merely phenomenological constructions.
Two references for understanding how our the interaction of our bodies and brains create our representations of the world are:

Shapiro, L. (2019), Embodied Cognition. New York: Routledge.
Shea, N. (2018), Representation in Cognitive Science. Oxford: Oxford U.P.

Since there are a lot of resources here, I would start with the tertiary articles for an overview, and then start with Berto and Plebani followed by Shapiro. The introductory text to ontology will arm you with the basic vocabulary for talking about the details of ontology beyond the usual high-level discourse of emergence typical of a general philosopher. The embodied cognition treatise will arm you with concepts for shifting from the paradigm that representations are a product of the brain to the paradigm that representations are a product of the interaction of the body with the world.
Good luck!

This answer will be a criticism of your premise rather than references endorsing it.
When you state:

The emergent behaviors claimed to be observed in certain phenomena are not inherent to the phenomena themselves but are artifacts of the mental representations and interpretations of researchers, who may be unaware of this process.

you ARE denying that things like ant hills, brains, tornados species, and art exist or cans do “_____ things”.  You are explicitly denying the reality of all emergent objects or phenomenon.
It IS true that our minds are involved in developing the categories that are the assumed emergent phenomenon.  It is untrue that this means they do not exist.  You mistakenly call this process naive realism.  No, it is indirect realism, not direct realism.  Reality is inferred not directly experienced in indirect realism.
The essential role of the first person in this process is explicitly argued for by two authors I recommend.  The first is Karl Popper, the developer of our current science methodology.  Popper notes that ALL observations are first person.  Hence all our data is subjective.  Science uses several methodologies to try to harden our empirical use of this data against the self deception that individuals are subject to, but ultimately the best we can ever get to is intersubjective consensus on the validity if data and inferences based on it.  Subjectivity is intrinsic to all our knowledge.  A good intro to Poppers thinking is in his autobiography, An Unended Quest.  A good follow up would be his Conjectures and Refutations.
A second reference would be Ernest Nagle.  I have not read the relevant works he has published, but I know he argues at length that we CANNOT have a “view from nowhere”.  ALL inferences a conclusions must of necessity have a large suite of incompletely articulated and justified assumptions behind them.  I know this has to be true because of the Munchausen Trilemma, justifications must of necessity terminate in one of two fallacies, or an infinite series which has not been traversed.  Again, this is our human condition. We cannot ever get to the objectivity you hold as a standard for “reality”.
That our human framing around non reductive emergent phenomenon reflects real phenomena, processes and effects in our world —- that is just applying indirect realism to useful and consistent models and hypotheses.  There is no difference in the indirect realism method between reductive and emergent inference. Deny emergence, based on its subjectivity, and you deny reduction as well.
Learning to live with subjectivity, and ways to develop a worldview and world view evaluation methods that are generally useful in sorting better from worser views — THAT is one of the major challenges that philosophy is called upon to address!


The emergent behaviors claimed to be observed in certain phenomena are not inherent to the phenomena themselves but are artifacts of the mental representations and interpretations of researchers, who may be unaware of this process.

You're going to have to be more specific about which phenomena and behaviors you're talking about. Is it possible that some behaviors claimed to be emergent from some phenomena are really artifacts of the mental representations of researchers? Sure. In this case the researcher would be making a mistake, seeing something that isn't there. N-rays are an example of this. Supposedly N-rays were faintly visible to the eye in a dark room, and could be bent by an aluminum prism. Some researchers claimed they could see them. And yet, when the prism was secretly removed, the researchers observed no difference in the N-rays. Really, they were imagining the N-rays, similar to how some people claim to be able to see "auras."
Are most such behaviors really artifacts of the mental representations of researchers? No. Ants use pheromone trails to signal paths towards food sources, resulting in other ants finding shorter and shorter paths to the food, and researchers are not imagining this. Ant colonies really do find short paths to food sources and that is why. Human intelligence emerges from the interaction of billions of neurons, and researchers are not imagining this. Humans really are intelligent (eh, more or less) and their neurons are why.
I see that in a comment you linked to the lesswrong critique of the word "emergence." In brief, Yudkowsky thinks "emergence" is a useless word because it doesn't specifically explain anything. How does human intelligence arise from the neurons? To say it "emerges" does not really explain the process.
This critique has some validity, although it doesn't seem too related to the actual question you asked (which is whether the emergent behaviors are imagined, which they mostly are not).
But I think there is a way in which the word "emergence" can be useful. To say a behavior is "emergent" says that the behavior results entirely from the interactions of little parts known to the speaker. It says: don't go looking for gods or spirits, don't go looking for a clockmaker or a morphogenetic field. The little parts that explain the behavior are the obvious, mundane ones, the ones we already know about, and even though it's hard to see how the global behavior arises from them, it does arise from them somehow without needing any major external influence.
In other words, the word "emergence" is something of a bulwark against "god of the gaps" type arguments. "We don't know how X works, therefore it must be God (or my unlikely pet hypothesis)!" No - we know complex behavior can emerge from simple parts, so even if we don't know the details fully yet, we don't need an extra external explanation for the complexity.


The emergent behaviors claimed to be observed in certain phenomena are not inherent to the phenomena themselves but are artifacts of the mental representations and interpretations of researchers, who may be unaware of this process.

In simple words, emergence would be a subjective perception, not an objective fact.
I think Ilya Prigogine is the most prominent scientist who sustains this idea, and it seems quite logic (it is my personal position as well). Check this example:
Imagine two isolated systems: one is just a dot, and the other is a system made of two dots. Both systems in isolation can only produce elements in zero-th (dot) and one dimension (line). But when you relate both systems (remember that a system is an interrelated group of parts, where parts are also systems and systems are also parts of others), when you relate both systems... EMERGENCE! Now, we can have elements in two dimensions!
Has something really emerged on such ensemble, objectively, scientifically, or it has just emerged subjectively, metaphysically? The answer is clear: emergence -at least in this example- is purely subjective.
Yes, we can argue that this is obvious with metaphysical systems (arithmetics and geometry deal only with metaphysical, not physical objects). But the problem is always subjective. A person is not a physical system. Physically, it is just a set of atoms.
Emergence is always subjective, because systems are subjective perceptions.
If we state that conscience has emerged from a set of basic systems (a bunch of sand) that mixed together form a new whole, an individual (not a bunch of sand, but a person), the interpretation we give here is metaphysical, not physical. Physically, a person is just a bunch of atoms, and it would evidently behave differently from any part of it just because it is different. If the observer creates an interpretation which implies an emergent behavior, it is still a subjective interpretation.
Many sustain that life is the most clear example of emergence: basic substances, interrelated as a whole emerge life. The problem here is what is life, which is an old philosophical problem which is not solved. For many, atoms are alive. In final terms, life is an arbitrary judgement of physical objects. Is a leaf just taken from a tree, alive? Is a hair alive? is a finger alive? How much of a finger I should cut to be considered alive? Is a virus alive? Is ChatGPT alive?
It is simpler to understand that a system is a subjective perception, produced by our inherent rational (metaphysical) and empirical (physical) biases. A physical body is not a set of physical systems, because there are no physical frontiers/limits/boundaries between the liver and the lungs. Any boundary is the result of a rational (metaphysical) judgement. Physically, all the universe is just a bunch of atoms or fields, whatever.
If a system is a subjective perception, then, evidently, emergence is necessarily a subjective perception.

Is the fact that 12 = 4*3 nothing more than a subjective perception?

@causative Right. Numbers are ideal, not physical entities. Not a perception, though, but a judgement (see Kant).

The solar "system" would still have its behavior of planets circling and influencing each other in complex ways even if no one was looking. Your car doesn't stop being a car when you fall asleep (assuming you are not driving at the time). Your argument is basically the same as Idealism: things are what they are because of us. No.
